# extracting json info from api call for comparison in go

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON file like this one, which i use to update the info from a server:

```
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "environment": "dev",
      "features": [
        { "name": "newa", "enable": true },
        { "name": "newb", "enable": true }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The query to the API to get the info from the server returns the JSON info like this. I get this info through a function called **apicall()**

```
{
  "name": "Default",
  "environments": [
    "dev",
    "prod"
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "release",
      "name": "newa",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-01T11:01:53.054Z",
      "lastSeenAt": null,
      "stale": false,
      "environments": [
        {
          "name": "dev",
          "enabled": true,
          "type": "dev",
          "sortOrder": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "prod",
          "enabled": false,
          "type": "prod",
          "sortOrder": 200
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "release",
      "name": "newb",
      "createdAt": "2022-01-01T11:01:53.087Z",
      "lastSeenAt": null,
      "stale": false,
      "environments": [
        {
          "name": "dev",
          "enabled": true,
          "type": "dev",
          "sortOrder": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "prod",
          "enabled": false,
          "type": "prod",
          "sortOrder": 200
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "members": 1,
  "version": 1
}
```

Every time that i update the JSON file (e.g delete, create and update features info) the new info should be updated propertly in the server through an API call.

To delete, create and update features info in the server i have already a function call **apiupdate()**. Basically what i can update/create/delete from the JSON file is the feature name **environments.environment.features.name** and enable/disable it **environments.environment.features.enable**

Every time the file is updated a function will be triggered to update the new info into the server. So i have to compare the current JSON file with the information extracted from the server to make the proper changes.

What i tried so far is just to create the feature name if it's not present in the json file:

```
func triggered(token string, filejson string) {

    data := FeatureVars(filejson)
    for _, env := range data.Environments {
        for _, feature := range env.Features {

            url := "xxxx"
            response := statusfeature(url, token)
            fmt.Printf("response:%s", response)

            if response != "200 OK" {

                // Calling apiupdate()
                apiupdate(url_base, token, feature.Name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where statusfeature is:

```
func statusfeature(url string, token string) string {
    // Setup the request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", token)

    // Executing request
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }

    // Close response body as required
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    r := fmt.Sprintf("%d %s", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))
    fmt.Printf("response:%s", r)

    return r
}
```

For example, if i delete the feature name **newa** from the original JSON file, now i need to compare the information extracted from the server through the function **apicall()** in JSON and delete this feature name from the server through the funcion **apiupdate()**

**The issue is that i'm struggling with the comparison between the info extracted from the server in JSON and the JSON file which i use to update the server's current info. Is it necessary here to use json.Unmarshal() for the comparision?**

How would you do to compare the existing JSON file with the info extracted from the server in JSON to make the corresponding changes? I would like to make the comparision in a new function when the original JSON file is modified so i can update the server's info.

Any documentation/example in golang that i can use for that?

Comment: What do you mean with "delete this feature from the server"? Just that the `"features"` list in the response won't hold the deleted feature entry anymore? I think you should strip all the unrelated infos from your question, it's hard to understand what you're actually struggeling with.
Btw. I'ld advice against `DefaultClient` b/c it doesn't have a timeout set, meaning a connection loss (malevolent or by accident) will result in an ever-open connection. In the long run, the number of open connections might grow until the server crashes.

Comment: @NotX the question is clear "How would you do to compare the existing JSON file with the info extracted from the server in JSON to make the corresponding changes?". I've already updated the original question to clarify it. When talking about "features" i'm talking just about feature names. I already have functions to create those feature names into the server i'm struggling just with the comparison so i need to know if some feature names have to be created/deleted/updated into the server --> JSON comparison between the JSON file i use to update info and the JSON info extracted from the seever.

Comment: I still don't get it. You can parse a `string` to a `map` or a `struct` with `json.Unmarshal()`, and then you can step through it and compare whatever values you want. Is your question how to use the unmarshaler? Is your question how to step through the values? Is it something completely different?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with json.Unmarshall() so i'm not sure how can i use the unmarshaler and step through the values just to compare what i have in the json file and the info extracted from the server. An example/some info similar to the comparision i need to do it would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not completely sure what you're looking for, but here's a sketch on how to parse json data and step through it:

You can either parse your data into a nested `map[string]interface{}`, which is more compact but becomes annoying to work with in case there are many fields - you have to do type casting all the time.

Alternatively, you can declare struct types representing the structure of the json data (at least of the required fields). You can use tools like https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to avoid the manual work.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
)

type APIConfig struct {
    Environments []struct {
        Environment string `json:"environment"`
        Features    []struct {
            Name   string `json:"name"`
            Enable bool   `json:"enable"`
        } `json:"features"`
    } `json:"environments"`
}

type StatusFeature struct {
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Environments []string `json:"environments"`
    Features     []struct {
        Type         string      `json:"type"`
        Name         string      `json:"name"`
        CreatedAt    time.Time   `json:"createdAt"`
        LastSeenAt   interface{} `json:"lastSeenAt"`
        Stale        bool        `json:"stale"`
        Environments []struct {
            Name      string `json:"name"`
            Enabled   bool   `json:"enabled"`
            Type      string `json:"type"`
            SortOrder int    `json:"sortOrder"`
        } `json:"environments"`
    } `json:"features"`
    Members int `json:"members"`
    Version int `json:"version"`
}

func main() {
    fromConfigString := `{environments": [{"environment": "dev",---"...` // truncated for readability, your config
    var apiConfig APIConfig // we create an empty instance of APIConfig
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(fromConfigString), &apiConfig) // since you example seems to use strings, we need to convert them to byte slices
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    statusFeatureString := `{"name":"Default","environments": ["dev","prod" ], ...` // truncated for readability, your server response
    var statusFeature StatusFeature // we create an empty instance of StatusFeature
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(statusFeatureString), &statusFeature)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, fCE2 := range apiConfig.Environments {
        var found bool
        // it's probably nicer to extract the nested search loops into a separate method and just return true or false,
        // but I keep it here for the sake of compactness
    search:
        for _, fCF := range fCE2.Features {
            for _, fS := range statusFeature.Features {
                if fS.Name == fCF.Name {
                    found = true
                    break search
                }
            }
        }
        if found {
            // the feature from the config was found in the response. Do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using nested for loops it’s not a good solution to compare the state of the server’s info. If the Json files contains the following features FeatA, FeatB, FeatW, FeatZ and the server FeatB, FeatA, FeatY, FeatV it’s not easy to sync the server with the Json file’s info. Finally, what I did is just to clean up the server’s info every time I need to update some specific feature name. It’s not the best way to achieve that but I dis not find any other way through nested for loops.

Comment: If you don't want to loop, you need a `map` structure. So, parse it as a `map[string]interface{}` and access the names of the features directly. Apart from that you did neigher tell that you you want to move work from the client to the server, nor that have _so_ many features that looping would become slow (and can't really imagine that you have). ;)